# Magento 2x web rest api: Anyone can tell me about endpoint to get order status from store configuration?

Tags: magento2, configuration, order-status, webapi

I wonder if there is endpoint to get orderstatus by using api in magento 2x. As I check there is issue that created since 2016 but closed because report in github [link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7084)

Comment: I'm not sure if there is, but creating such an endpoint is fairly easy.

Comment: what you mean by "creating such an endpoint is fairly easy" ?

Comment: Well, API creation is documented here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-to-web-service.html all that is left to do is find the entity that tracks the order status values.

Comment: All possible values are stored in the sales_order_status table

Comment: this thing, mean i need to custom client magento code ?

Comment: Yes. The solution I'm proposing requires a custom module.

Comment: thank you but I cannot go and custom like that

Comment: there's no specific endpoint for that unless you define your own

Comment: @fmsthird I just want to get order status something like /V1/stores/orderStatus that can get all order status in magento.